# How can I start an activity before application's oncreate

Tags: android

I am making an app that has an application class. I want the application to remain till the point the app is killed. But I also want that whatever is done in the application's **oncreate()** to be done after taking input from the user. So I have an activity which takes the data from the user. So, is there a way I can **launch that activity's oncreate first before the application's oncreate** because by default the **first thing** that is executed is **application's oncreate()**.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate()` is the first step in the app lifecycle and, as such, there is nothing before `onCreate()`. You can't do something in something that doesn't exist yet.

What you might want to do is have two different activities, one where you get the data you need from the user, and another one that you call once you have received the data you need.

Comment: I know that onCreate() is the first step. But, I can't follow the method you mentioned, can't be done because, I want the user entered data over all my activities. So I have to have it in application class.That's why I was asking that can anyway, the default order can be changed.

Comment: You are looking at this from the wrong direction. If you want that data to be accessible in all your activities, there are methods to do so: shared preferences, bundles, sqlite databases, whichever you prefer (and which is most suited to the data being saved).